# validating input to the asp:CreateUserWizard control

Tags: asp.net, validation

I'm using the asp:CreateUserWizard control and have read on MSDN:

> User input in a Web page can potentially contain malicious client
>   script. By default, ASP.NET Web pages validate user input to ensure
>   that the input does not contain HTML elements or script. As long as
>   this validation is enabled

This is the code I'm using:

```
<asp:Label runat="server" AssociatedControlID="UserName">User name</asp:Label>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="UserName" CausesValidation="true"/>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName"
   CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="User name is required." />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="UserName" 
   CssClass="field-validation-error" ErrorMessage="User name must not contain \ (backslashes)." 
   ValidationExpression="[^\\]*" />
```

Now if I try and create a user with a name like `<script>alert('hello')</script>` my app then crashes with a 500 internal error.

I've tried code in all these events to see if I can trap the error but the code never gets hit:

```
RegisterUser_CreateUserError()
RegisterUser_CreatingUser()
```

So my 2 questions are, why is the input not being validated and where could I trap this error when it is thrown (the 2nd question maybe less important once I know how to do the first part)?

I must be missing something really simple here.

Comment: You can not enter any HTML tags in textbox. It is Injection in the code. ASP.net will validate it before Begin_Request event. You will not get exception in the page level or even application level. Why do you want to add such scripts in textbox "<script>alert('hello')</script>"? Its like hack and script injection. This is not a valid input.

Comment: Because I'm "testing" to make sure that scripts exploits can't be attempted via this control

Comment: If you want then you can stop error by adding <%@ Page validateRequest="false" %> at top of your page but it is not recommended. This is page level. But you can stop request validation at control level like ValidateRequestMode="Disabled" in TextBox

Comment: I want the control to be validated, but I would not expect a 500 error to be returned when the control has HTML or script entered into it, this does not seem the behaviour I would expect, a 500 indicates a crash/error

Comment: No. You should not do that. This is not by mistake input this is like hack. That is why it should get prohibited before request comes to your application data. If you want to test add any random data such as \\\ .. like this and test it. If anyone does that application should not allow that user to enter data.